# What is the maximum attainable level of a Steam account?

Tags: steam

**What is the maximum attainable level of a Steam account ?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a hard limit. However, you'd hit a soft limit after crafting every single available badge. The exception is during winter and summer sales, which have badges that can be levelled an infinite number of times.